# How to pass basic auth after SSO redirect?

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress and JS. The app I am testing redirects to a stub IDP page if not logged in. The app is also behind basic auth. All I am doing in the test is

`cy.visit("https://username:password@app_url.com")`

This redirects me to the stub IDP page where I am clicking login button as

`cy.contains('button', 'Log in').click()`. This redirects back to the app home page.

However, upon redirect, it's prompting me to fill in basic auth again. Is there a way to pass basic auth headers that are remembered after the redirect?

The stub IDP is for SAML based SSO and it's too much work or I should say I lack knowledge to create a server request to obtain auth token. So looking for a simple work around for now.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and I just solved it using `cy.intercept()`!

You have to use `cy.intercept` on the new redirected URL and add the basic authorization header to the request.

1. **generate the basic auth header**, you can generate it here: https://www.blitter.se/utils/basic-authentication-header-generator/
2. **find the target URL**, for you its the app home page.

- maybe there are several redirects, you can find the final one with basic auth when running the test in open mode and after canceling the popped-out window, you will see this in the runner

[image: redirected url]

- the "new url" is the one you want

3. **in the test, add the `intercept()` command before clicking the button.** Add the authorization header to the outgoing request, that is triggered when the test is being redirected.

```js
cy.intercept(`<TARGET_URL>`, (req) => {
  req.headers['Authorization'] = `<BASIC_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE>`;
});
```

here you can read more about adding headers to outgoing request and intercept functionality:
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Adding-a-header-to-an-outgoing-request